# Service Cloud Fundamental

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Like we have RecruitingApp in Platform Fundamental, i was wondering do we have any same help book for service cloud and console application learning.

please advice as i am looking for such book since one week and unable to find.
How can i learn console and service cloud. Any suggestion are welcome

Answer (score 0):

[Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) is new workbook and better than books .Both of topics you need to learn  had a Trailhead modules available

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/service_basics

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/service_console_customize

Also the service cloud workbook link below

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_service_cloud.meta/workbook_service_cloud/